# Display Information into a HTML Table

Tags: jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap, minecraft

I am pulling a JSON GET from http://status.mojang.com/check 
This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="status">
       <table class="table table-striped">
         <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>Service</td>
           <td>Description</td>
           <td>Status</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>skins.minecraft.net</td>
           <td>Minecraft Skins</td>
         </tr>
```

And what I want it to do is:

- If the server is online (JSON Response "green") I would like it to display the Bootstrap button "success"
- If the servers are quite slow (JSON Response "yellow") it would display the bootstrap button "warning"
- If the servers are offline (JSON Response "red") display the bootstrap button "danger".

Comment: where's your jquery code? simply add class when success.

Comment: Bootstrap and Minecraft tags in the same question. Mind...blown.